# odoo 8 change from models.Model to osv.osv

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In my odoo 8 itu use two kind of class, models.Model and osv.osv and I need it to change form models.Model to osv.osv

```
class purchase_extend2(models.Model):
_inherit = 'purchase.order'

allowed_credit = fields.Float(string="Customer Debt", compute="_get_allowed_credit", )

@api.one
@api.depends('customer_id')
def _get_allowed_credit(self):
    invoice_pool = self.env['account.invoice']
    confirmed_so_objs = invoice_pool.search([('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', self.customer_id.id)])
    self.allowed_credit = sum([so.amount_total for so in confirmed_so_objs])
```

how to change it into this class?

```
class purchase_extend2(osv.osv):
```

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to change?

Comment: because I need to use the class in other module which is used the osv.osv class

Comment: You don't need to, because it's the same, [look here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/osv/osv.py).

Comment: I've tried but it show error: No module named exceptions

Comment: There is no import in your code example. Please add that and also add the Error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [functional field](https://doc.odoo.com/v6.0/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type/#functional-fields)

***Example:***

```py
from openerp.osv import osv, fields


class PurchaseOrderExtend(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    def _get_allowed_credit(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context):
        res = {}
        invoice_pool = self.pool.get('account.invoice')
        for order in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            confirmed_so_objs = invoice_pool.search_read(cr, uid, [('state', '=', 'open'), ('partner_id', '=', order.partner_id.id)], ['amount_total'])
            res[order.id] = {'allowed_credit': sum(so['amount_total'] for so in confirmed_so_objs)}
        return res

    _columns = {
        'allowed_credit': fields.function(_get_allowed_credit, type="float", string="Customer Debt", multi='_get_allowed_credit')
    }
```

To use exceptions, use the following import:

```
from openerp.exceptions import Warning
```

Comment: Yes thank you Kenly, this is what I need. But it doesn't get the value. It only get 0.

Comment: It depends on the result of the `search_read` method, I tested it, and it is working.  Try to create an invoice for the same partner, confirm the invoice then check if it recomputes the field value in the purchase order.

Comment: but Kenly, I use this function when I want to make an invoice and choose the customer

Comment: Of course, It is just a test, try to make an invoice and choose a partner then Odoo will calculate the value

Comment: Yes I have tried but still it doesn't work. In models.Model, it works flawlessly. Please help.

Comment: Did you use the same code? Because I tested it using the partner_id field and when I receive an invoice and confirm it, the ``allowed_credit`` is updated correctly

Comment: Did you fix that error?